# Determine object type by number

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class with many derived types, and I have a unique number associated with each derived class. Is there a simple way to match a number with a derived type?

Some pseudo code:

```
class foo{
public:
    virtual int bar(int) = 0;
}

class fan:foo{
public:
    int bar(int num){ return num * 5; )
}

class fawn:foo{
public:
    int bar(int num){ return num * 9; );
}



int main(){
    vector<foo*> obj;
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ){
        int num = rand() % 2;
        if( num == 0 )
            obj.push_back( new fan() );
        if( num == 1 )
            obj.push_back( new fawn() );
    }
}
```

This does what I want, but I have many more than two classes, and I plan to add many more. Is there any way to do this in a less verbose manner?

I'm using MinGW, if it matters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Basically, you'll make something like this:

```
class foo
{
   ...
   static foo* Create(int num);
}

foo* foo::Create(int num)
{
   foo* instance;
   switch (num)
   {
      case 0:
         instance = new fan();
         break;
      case 1:
         instance = new fawn();
         break;

      ...
   }
   return instance;
}
```

There is no way to get rid of the enumeration, but at least this way you'll have to construct it exactly once and then you can use it everywhere `foo` is visible.

Edit: Personally I like the above style but a more compact version is

```
foo* foo::Create(int num)
{
   if (num==0) return new fan();
   if (num==1) return new fawn();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, well I've been mulling over this for quite a while, and even my most clever of solutions require all that typing. It's annoying, but I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes. Thank you.

Comment: @Aslai Anyway, happy to help.

Comment: Alright, well, even though they're evil, I'll just use a `#define` macro to make it even more compact. I just wanted to confirm that I wasn't wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum for unique identifiers for your derived types.

Then you can just have a field within your derived classes containing this enum, which you set in their respective constructors. That way you can just have a single function to retrieve its type.